# iOS - OAuth implementation how to create Framework ? (simple)

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth

**Hi**,

I need to **include OAuth** in my Project, to do that i found this simple "tuto".
But i don't understand **how can i go from the provided files to a compiled framework file.**

This is what they say :

> - Importing the Framework There are 3 steps for adding the pre-compiled
>     framework to your app in Xcode:
>
>   - Drag the framework into your Linked Frameworks group in Xcode,
>       choosing to copy the framework instead of simply referencing it.
>   - Create a new Copy Files Build Phase for your app's main target.
>   - Drag the framework from the Linked Frameworks folder into the new Copy
>       Files Build Phase and select "Frameworks" as its destination.
>
> For now, please use this as a private embedded framework rather than copying it
>   to the system's framework folder upon installation.

The framework : [OAuthLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer)

**When i compile it i get an .a file then, i don't understand what to do. (What is the Linked Frameworks group) ? Where i put this .a file ?**

Thanks.

---

**Edit : I'v just found this [RSOAuthEngine - OAuth with ARC](https://github.com/rsieiro/RSOAuthEngine) but it's for OAuth 1.
I'm looking for same think but for OAuth 2.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OAuthLibrary's web page, it appears to target Mac OS X only, not iOS.

Also, iOS doesn't support frameworks built by third parties. Static libraries are supported, however. So you would need to (1) build a static library with the OAuthLibrary source files, or (2) incorporate the source files directly into your app's project. But this doesn't alter the fact that the library appears to be designed for Mac OS X only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't see that was only for OS X.
I'll use https://github.com/thekarladam/MPOAuth instead.
By the way, it's hard to find some source using ARC. If you have any link, thanks for sending.